# problems with kcfinder image browser in Chrome

Tags: civimail, images

There did not use to be a problem with the media browser in CiviMail when using Chrome, but it's broken now.

https://BASEURL/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/js/index.php 3.12

WORKS in Firefox: shows KCFinder: /image33 files (4 MB)

Does not work/Hangs showing "CIVICRM File Manager" as heading
Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97

Other reports of hanging while trying to upload or select images.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention CMS but if this is Drupal then I would recommend you upgrade to 7.71 due to

- [Fix for jQuery Form bug in Chromium-based browsers](https://www.drupal.org/node/3143016)

Comment: I was using Drupal 7.71; now after security release today, I'm on 7.72. Jquery update version is  7.x-2.7 and uses 1.10 Jquery version. I have now install the alpha version and upgraded the jquery_update to 3.1. No joy on either front.

Comment: sorry to hear that. i can't recall hitting this issue - just a few clients have said 'problems uploading' (not certain if they were all drupal or some were civi forms) and have then confirmed it works in FF and not in Chrome, and so we updated Drupal and didn't hear back. Have now just done the security upgrade for all of them too.

Comment: I have Chrome Version 80.0.3987.137 (Official Build) (64-bit) on my Chromebook and it works like a charm. It's certainly something with Chrome 83. I'm not entirely convinced it's the same jquery-Ajax bug discussed in the thread you mentioned--or more to the point, it looks like the kcfinder script includes it's own version of jquery code which would make a Drupal core patch not help? Knowing this is Chrome's bug and should eventually be fixed once Chrome gets to version 85 may make working on it not worthwhile.